# How to call method once instead some times?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have the following structure DOM in angular:

```
<div
      class="column"
      *ngFor="let cols of numberReturn(cols); let c = index"
      (click)="select(getMatrix(r, c))"
      title="{{ getMatrix(r, c).title }}"
      [ngClass]="{ active: isToolSelected(getMatrix(r, c)) }"></div>
```

As you can see I call sometimes `getMatrix(r, c)`.

How to call this once and pass result everywhere like:

```
let r = getMatrix(r, c);
(click)="select(r)"
title="{{ r.title }}"
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attach the value of `getMatrix(r, c)` with each object of your `cols` array inside `numberReturn` and access by  key for example your `numberReturn` will look like

```
numberReturn(cols){
var retVal=[];//array your return here
retVal.forEach((item,index)=>{
item['matrixVal']=this.getMatrix(this.r,index);
})
}
```

then on ui

```
<div
      class="column"
      *ngFor="let cols of numberReturn(cols); let c = index"
      (click)="select(cols.matrixVal)"
      title="{{ cols.matrixVal.title }}"
      [ngClass]="{ active: isToolSelected(cols.matrixVal) }"></div>
```